# jQuery .not() and .each() with nested span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am editing the value of a span that has another span nested within it. I am trying to essentially exclude the class of the nested span within my `.each()` function.

The code edits the price value buy subtracting a percentage from it, issue is it also edits the currency code span, by removing it.

```
$('.price').each(function() {

    var val = $(this).text();
    var num = parseFloat(val);
    var discount = num - (num * .40);

  $(this).text(discount);
});
```

HTML Looks like this:

```
- <span class="price">1000 <span class="currency">KR</span></span><br>
- <span class="price">100 <span class="currency">KR</span></span><br>
- <span class="price">2000 <span class="currency">KR</span></span><br>
- <span class="price">6000 <span class="currency">KR</span></span><br>
- <span class="price">10000 <span class="currency">KR</span></span>
```

To exclude the nested div `<span class="currency">KR</span>` I am running the following:

```
$('.price').not('.currency').each(function() { //etc etc });
```

It's important to note that the logic must be this way, I can only use a nested `<span>`.

Comment: While it's possible the way it is, it would be easier to separate the numerical value in the outputted HTML, i.e. `<span class="price"><span class="value">1000</span> <span class="currency">KR</span></span>`, and target `$('.price .value')`

Comment: `$('.price').not('.currency')` will ignore `class="price currency"` not children of `.price` that are `.currency`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.contents()` it will return all the nodes including the text node, pick the first one and calculate the discount, not pick the second node, prepend the discount and set the new string as the html.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.price').each(function() {

    var val = $(this).contents()[0].textContent;
    var num = parseFloat(val);
    var discount = num - (num * .40);
    $(this).html(function(){
        return $(this).html().replace(val, discount+" ");
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="price">1000 <span class="currency">KR</span></span>
<br>
<span class="price">100 <span class="currency">KR</span></span>
<br>
<span class="price">2000 <span class="currency">KR</span></span>
<br>
<span class="price">6000 <span class="currency">KR</span></span>
<br>
<span class="price">10000 <span class="currency">KR</span></span>
```

Comment: Thanks, While it works I need that `<span class="currency">KR</span>` intact as an external plugin relies on it (which i have no control over) and this eliminates that span.

Comment: Thanks brother! Works nicely.